# How to add a Sound Hover Effect on my page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the Rock Paper Scissors Game. Here is part of my original code without sound effect. I want to add a sound effect on the id of "r","p" & "s" which can play my audio when mouse over those button. I tried the method from other tutorials, but it still can't work. Can anyone help me with this issue. Thanks

HTML

```
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice" id="r"></div>
        <div class="choice" id="p">✋</div>
        <div class="choice" id="s">✌️</div>

    <div class="resultAnnounce">
        <p>                </p>

    <div class = "roundCount">  
        <p>                 </p>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function main() {
    rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
        game('r');
    })

    paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
        game('p');
    })

    scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
        game('s');
    })
    
}

main();
```

Comment: Can you please share the rest of your code? What is `rock_div`, `paper_div`, and `scissors_div`? Those variables are not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This [example][1] here on codepen works fine for me. The trick is to add eventlisteners for mouseover and mouseleave.

```
hearbeat = document.getElementById('heartbeat')

resetBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
heartbeat.play();
}, false);

resetBtn.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  heartbeat.pause();
  heartbeat.currentTime = 0;
}, false);
```

If it doesn't work it may be that your browser doesn't support the audio tag.